# Frequency table of multiple columns

Tags: r

I have huge dataset with 16000rows and 2800 categorical columns. i want to make a matrix in which rows = variable name and column =labels. i have tried with apply function with table  but i am getting this result in list format.

```
data= sapply(mydata, table)
output
var1
1               2         3          4        5
1855    8520    1117   1700    2568
var2
-1         - 2      - 3      0       1    2
5642  2634 5218 321 745 605
```

Comment: Do all of your categorical variables have the same number of levels?

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include part of your data (use e.g. `dput`).

Comment: Maybe this is not possible, if the columns have a different numbers of levels, the result will be a list with members of different lengths.

Comment: Is this it `sapply(mydata, function(x) table(levels(x)[x]))`?

Comment: Hi Rui thanks for reply... i have total 187 unique levels... and all the categorical variables are not have same variables. I am getting my result in list format but i want the result in matrix format with 2800*187.

Comment: HI G5W, Maurits,  i have total 187 unique levels... and all the categorical variables are not have same variables. I am getting my result in list format but i want the result in matrix format with 2800*187.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
```

Using iris as an example.

```
str(iris)
   'data.frame':    150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Below is a wrapper function that creates frequency table for all columns, remember to replace iris with your data set.

```
freq <- function (...) {
  iris %>% count(...) %>% arrange(desc(n))
}
```

Using apply to send all columns to function freq.

```
a <- apply(X = iris,MARGIN = 2,freq)
```

Using for loop to modify individual dataframe with in a (a list object).

```
for (i in 1:length(a)) {
  a[[i]]$Column <- names(a[i])
  print(i)
  names(a[[i]]) <- c("Variable","n","Column_name")
}
```

Using do.call() to bind all rows.

```
final <- do.call(rbind,a) %>% data.frame() %>% select(Column_name,Variable,n)
```

Final result for iris is as below.

[image]

Comment: Error in captureDots(strict = `__quosured`) : 
  the argument has already been evaluated

Comment: Error in a[i] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Error in do.call(rbind, a) : second argument must be a list

Comment: it would be helpful if you could post your code along with the error. So that I can see which line created the error